# PointerProperty can not dispaly in UILayout

Tags: scripting

```py
import bpy
class AddPreset(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Preset"
    bl_idname = "test.preset_add"
    mat_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Str Props")
    mat: bpy.props.PointerProperty(name="Pointer Props", type=bpy.types.Material)

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):        
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        #row.prop_search(self, "mat", bpy.data, "materials")
        #row.prop_search(self, "mat_name", bpy.data, "materials")
        row.prop(self, "mat")

bpy.utils.register_class(AddPreset)
bpy.ops.test.preset_add('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

output info

```
rna_uiItemR: property not found: TEST_OT_preset_add.mat
```

My Temporary method is use StringProperty.
So is that possible to use PointerProperty？